# truffle migration: tokenName and tokenSymbol do not show up in explorer (Ropsten)

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle-migration

I created an ERC20 contract with Truffle, everything went right except for one thing: the name and symbol of the token does not show up in etherscan.

I used the ERC20.sol provided by openZeppelin.
My contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.6.0;

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Erc20Token is ERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowed;
    string public tokenName;
    string public tokenSymbol;
    uint256 public decimals;
    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    constructor(string memory _tokenName, string memory _tokenSymbol, uint256 totalSupply, uint256 _decimals) public {
        tokenName = _tokenName;
        tokenSymbol = _tokenSymbol;
        decimals = _decimals;
        _totalSupply = totalSupply;
        _mint(msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }
}
```

and the migration contract:

```
var Erc20Token = artifacts.require("./ERC20Token.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Erc20Token, "qwerty", "qty", 100000000000000, 8);
};
```

Here is an example of a transaction, under "Tokens Transferred" we should find tokenName(tokenSymbol). Any idea of what the problem might be ?

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xecd975fdc2652ac12019cee8b32155f8b694ec5dff89613436d97c448b8852be

Comment: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x39ca10bb80d2c2864faf3a261440b3eb21aeefd5#code is not verified on Etherscan (you should verify it).

Comment: I was unable to verify this contract: always get "Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI". So I put all the code in a single file, created a new contract and was able to verify it without any difference: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xa7f20c525d82be6710d85f0d66925c72d07bbe3d

Comment: So now `tokenName` and `tokenSymbol` are visible at https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xa7f20c525d82be6710d85f0d66925c72d07bbe3d#readContract.

Comment: And if you had named them `name` and `symbol` as dictated by the ERC20 standard, then they would have also been visible at https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0xa7f20c525d82be6710d85f0d66925c72d07bbe3d.

Comment: That was my problem :-)))))))